# Images with blurring in the center

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, image-editing, image-processing, paint.net

I was trying to remember the name of a specific effect/coding which is applied to images, where the center of image (or any part) is clear and gradually quality decreases in a circular manner. What is it called? I remember it was something like "coveated coding" or something?! It is a technique in computer vision.

Something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect in the image resembles the Spin Blur effect in Photoshop. Spin blurs along concentric circles as shown in the image below. To find the Spin Blur in Photoshop select *Filter* -> *Blur Gallery* -> *Spin Blur...*

[image]

<sub>**Image Source:** [Understanding Adobe Photoshop CS6: The Essential Techniques for Imaging by Richard Harrington](https://books.google.com/books?id=JoOQPg2rPBoC&pg=RA1-PA6#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sub>

Comment: That's interesting. But the term Im trying to find is not really an effect inside a tool. It is an encoding approach; coveated coding or sth?!